# How can I store the root of a binary search tree if two structures are used?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

I have two structures and they are nested structures. In this case, one structure represents a grocery store while the other represents the food items sold at the store, for instance. These are the structures:

```
typedef struct store store;
typedef struct foodItem foodItem;

struct foodItem {
    char itemName[20];
    foodItem *prev, *next, *rootItem; //stores root item in BST
};

struct store {
    char storeName[20];
    store *prev, *next;
    foodItem *items;
} *rootStore; //stores root user in BST
```

The data inputted into the linked lists above are to be inserted into binary search trees (or BSTs). The issue I'm having is the concept of a root with the list of food items. The root of the BST for stores is simple because there is only one BST of stores, but there are many BSTs of food items because there are several stores. How can I reliable keep track of the root of each food item BST?

To solve this issue I attempted to put `*rootItem` into `struct foodItem` so each root node can be kept track of with a pointer, but that leads to the issue of every node in the BST having its own root (if my assessment of that issue is correct). Every food item BST should have its own root node, not each node its own root. Another solution I can think of would be to store a pointer inside `struct store` so each store can keep track of the root of its food item BST, but would that not lead to complications with accessing the root when its needed?

Any help you can give at the high-level or with code would be appreciated here.

Comment: *"How can I reliable keep track of the root of each food item BST?"* - you are already keeping track of it with the `.items` field of `struct store`. I don't really see the problem you're trying to solve here. At best, you are over-engineering it, you shouldn't need the `rootItem` element in `struct foodItem`. You fail to communicate what exactly you want to do and what problem exactly you want to solve with this. Be more clear, add an example and show why what you already tried does not work in your case. Define "keep track" more clearly, because currently it's really unclear what it means.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You actually answered my question with this comment by stating `.items` already keeps  track of it.